# react-router and context types

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I received such error when I try to pass router to the component Login:

```
class Login extends React.Component {

onClick(){
  Actions.login(this.context.router);
}

static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

render(){

    return (
        <Card style={{
          'maxWidth': '800px',
          'margin': '30px auto',
          'padding': '50px'
        }}>
          <CardText style={{
            'textAlign': 'center'
          }}>
            To start chatting away, please log in with your Google account.
          </CardText>

          <RaisedButton style={{
            display: 'block',
          }} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}
          label="Log in with Google" primary={true} />
        </Card>
    );
   }
 }

export default Login;
```

Then I try to pass it to the action `login` to make possible to redirect to the other route after logging. 
Action Login:

```
login(router){
return (dispatch) => {
  let firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://front-react-stack.firebaseio.com');
  firebaseRef.authWithOAuthPopup("google", (error, user) => {
    if(error){
      return;
    }

    dispatch(user);

    router.push('/chat');
  });

}
```

}

But after logging in the console there is an error:
  "warning: Failed Context Types: Invalid context `router` of type `object` supplied to `Login`, expected `function`. Check the render method of `RouterContext`."

It seems to me that I ve passed `func`. not an `object` type so I have no idea where this error come from...

Comment: Did you try console.log to see if it's a function or not? `this` might not be what you think it is inside of onClick

Answer (score 6):

`router`is an object:

Try this:

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the following:

```
router: function() { React.PropTypes.func.isRequired }
```